# Click function no longer working

Tags: jquery

I have the following page that works as I want it to, all the JS is in the  tags and no inline JS : http://www.ninjatrader-support.com/leins/SS/index.html
When I put this in production, and switched from the table to a div layout the "Next" and "Previous" buttons no longer work and I had to go back to inline JS in the PHP file that creates the returned table as seen here: https://www.kinetick.com/Test/supportTest.php#Symbol-Search

this pisses me off. What could cause the code to work in one instance but not the other? both buttons aren't in the page itself but created in the PHP file and inserted into the page. Please help this is killing me!

Here's the code that works on the support url

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$("#processing").hide();

var options = { 
    target: '#return',
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('#processing').show()
    },
    complete: function() {
        $('#processing').hide()
    }
    }; 
   $('#SymbolSearchForm').ajaxForm(options); 
}); 

function changestart(direction) 
{
var rowsElement  = $("#maxrows");
var rowsValue    = parseInt(rowsElement.val());
var startElement = $("#startID");
var value        = parseInt(startElement.val());
startElement.val(direction == "forward" ? value + rowsValue : direction == "back" ? value -
rowsValue : 1);
}
$("#previous").click(function(){changestart('back');});
$("#next").click(function(){changestart('forward');});
$("#lookup").click(changestart);
```

Comment: next and previous buttons are working for me on both ?

Comment: Yeah, like I said on the https://www.kinetick.com/Test/supportTest.php#Symbol-Search I had to go back to the inline JS coding in the PHP as such:{
 echo "<input type=\"submit\" id=\"previous\" name=\"previous\" value=\"&laquo;&nbsp;Previous\" onclick=\"changestart('back')\" />";
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps try:

```
$("#previous").live("click",function(){changestart('back');});
$("#next").live("click",function(){changestart('forward');});
$("#lookup").live("click",changestart);
```

In both examples, it looks like the 'Next' and 'Prev' buttons are created after you have set the .click() handler. The .live() handler let's you add an event listener even if the DOM elements change.

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: I just added the click functions into the "complete" function of the AJAX call. seemed to work, same thing?

Comment: Same effect in the end, but you'd be doing more work in the complete function. I'd set the live handler once and forget it.